# How to setup my EditText xml in Android

Tags: android

For allow user only can input lower case alphabet and number, how can I setup my EditText in a xml file ?

Sorry, I did not provide clear information. I just want to filter or check user's input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, your question is complicated to do. better get a input from user. then you can convert that string to lowercase using `toLowerCase()`.